# Error while compiling a rust file generated by c2rust. using rustc

Tags: rust, compilation, rust-cargo

I have a rust program named hello.rs.

The program is I'm unable to compile it using rustc. I generated the hello.rs using c2rust online transpiler. But if I use cargo run hello.rs the program runs smoothly.

When using rustc it shows the following error. How to fix it?

**The original hello.c file:**

```
    void main() {
       // printf() displays the string inside quotation
       printf("Hello, World!");
       
    }
```

**The hello.rs file.**

```
    #![allow(dead_code, mutable_transmutes, non_camel_case_types, non_snake_case,
             non_upper_case_globals, unused_assignments, unused_mut)]
    #![register_tool(c2rust)]
    #![feature(main, register_tool)]
    extern "C" {
        #[no_mangle]
        fn printf(_: *const libc::c_char, _: ...) -> libc::c_int;
    }
    unsafe fn main_0() {
        // printf() displays the string inside quotation
        printf(b"Hello, World!\x00" as *const u8 as *const libc::c_char);
    }
    #[main]
    pub fn main() { unsafe { main_0() } ::std::process::exit(0i32); }
```

**The error message:**

```
┌──(pegasus㉿pegasus)-[~/Documents/Rust_testing]
└─$ rustc hello.rs -o test2
error[E0557]: feature has been removed
 --> hello.rs:4:12
  |
4 | #![feature(main, register_tool)]
  |            ^^^^ feature has been removed

error: cannot find attribute `main` in this scope
  --> hello.rs:13:3
   |
13 | #[main]
   |   ^^^^
   |
   = note: `main` is in scope, but it is a function, not an attribute

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `libc`
 --> hello.rs:7:21
  |
7 | fn printf(_: *const libc::c_char, _: ...) -> libc::c_int;
  |                     ^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `libc`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `libc`
 --> hello.rs:7:46
  |
7 | fn printf(_: *const libc::c_char, _: ...) -> libc::c_int;
  |                                              ^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `libc`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `libc`
  --> hello.rs:11:52
   |
11 | printf(b"Hello, World!\x00" as *const u8 as *const libc::c_char);
   |                                                    ^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `libc`

warning: `#[no_mangle]` has no effect on a foreign function
 --> hello.rs:6:1
  |
6 | #[no_mangle]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: remove this attribute
7 | fn printf(_: *const libc::c_char, _: ...) -> libc::c_int;
  | --------------------------------------------------------- foreign function
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_attributes)]` on by default
  = warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
  = note: symbol names in extern blocks are not mangled

error: aborting due to 5 previous errors; 1 warning emitted

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0433, E0557.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
```

When using cargo it compiles and runs perfectly.

```
└─$ cargo run hello.rs                    
   Compiling Rust_testing v0.1.0 (/home/pegasus/Documents/Rust_testing)
warning: crate `Rust_testing` should have a snake case name
  |
  = note: `#[warn(non_snake_case)]` on by default
  = help: convert the identifier to snake case: `rust_testing`

warning: `Rust_testing` (bin "Rust_testing") generated 1 warning
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.17s
     Running `target/debug/Rust_testing hello.rs`
Hello, world!
```

When removing the #[] this code runs in the playground.

**here's the new.rs code:**

```
extern "C" {
    fn printf(_: *const libc::c_char, _: ...) -> libc::c_int;
}
unsafe fn main_0() {
    // printf() displays the string inside quotation
    printf(b"Hello, World!\x00" as *const u8 as *const libc::c_char);
}
pub fn main() { unsafe { main_0() } ::std::process::exit(0i32); }
```

But it still shows the three error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `libc`.

**Here's my Cargo.toml file:**

```
[package]
name = "Rust_testing"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, doesn't work for me with `cargo run` either. Neither does it in the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1ee2f20ea97be588b92fdeffe5c499c8

Comment: Maybe you need an old Rust version for this to work?

Comment: I had added the one that works in playground.
But still the rustc shows the libc error[E04333]

Comment: For the `libc` issue, you just need to `use libc;` in `new.rs` and add `libc = "0.2"` to your Cargo.toml in the `[dependencies]` section

Comment: @Andrew He is talking about a direct `rustc` invocation

Comment: @ZeshanAhmedNobin `rustc` does not contain a dependency manager. If you want to compile with `rustc` directly, you need to manage dependencies yourself. That's why `cargo` exists. Use `cargo build` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for me either, even with `cargo run`. I'm unsure, maybe this requires an old version of nightly Rust?

Either way, if you remove the questionable code, it works without a problem:

```rust
extern "C" {
    fn printf(_: *const libc::c_char, _: ...) -> libc::c_int;
}

unsafe fn main_0() {
    // printf() displays the string inside quotation
    printf(b"Hello, World!\n\x00" as *const u8 as *const libc::c_char);
}

pub fn main() {
    unsafe { main_0() }
    ::std::process::exit(0i32);
}
```

```
Hello, World!
```

---

You mention that it doesn't work with `rustc` directly. That is true, because `rustc` is a compiler, it is not a dependency manager. You need to link the dependencies manually if you don't want to use `cargo`. I highly recommend using `cargo`, though.

If you run `cargo run -vv` (of course run `cargo clean` before, otherwise you won't see anything), you can see how `cargo` adds the dependencies.